# Magento 2.3.4 does not complete index broken by Catalog Search indexing

Tags: magento2, product-reindexing

Running `bin/magento indexer:reindex`
results in the following error:

```
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface in /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Invento...', Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Invento...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Invento...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Amasty\\Shopby\\M...')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co in /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

Can do with help here?

Thanks

Comment: It looks that you have to execute bin/magento setup:di:compile to generate classes and try again :)

Comment: Try to remove generated folder "rm -rf generated/*" and compile again "bin/magento setup:di:compile"

Comment: Tried this solution but to no avail still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Found the offending mod as mentioned in the error message uninstalled amasty shopby,
It was also causing the category pages to show blank
compiled site and re-indexed and now working fine